# Is there a way in angular 2+ to force detect changes?

Tags: angular

I'm changing a component property, and it does not change immediately.

Tried to do it using `NgZone.run (() => { this.property = newValue })`,
also did not work (didn't change immediately).

```
playComputerMove() {
    const moveToMake: Move = this.minimax(this.cells, true, [], 9, -1000, 1000);

 //this.zone.run(() => { this.cells = moveToMake.moves[0]; });
 this.cells = moveToMake.moves[0];

 this.currTurn = { playerOption: FourInAPlayerOption.player1, image: 
 this.player1CellImage };

 if (this.isTerminalState(this.cells)) {
   alert("Game over!");
   this.isGameOver = true;
 }
}
```

I'm expecting that the change will render immediately, but it happens on the screen only after the alert("Game over").

Would love some help in this subject from those who experienced it with angular 2+.

Comment: Can you try to inject `ChangeDetectorRef` then call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` at the appropriate moment ? Note : even if it might work, it is probably not the best solution. It looks like there is a design flaw.

Comment: Okay so what is the design flaw? And why ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() is not a good solution? tnx for your help!

Comment: I don't know but having to call ChangeDetectorRef manually is suspicious.

Comment: Another option : maybe the usage of `window.alert()` blocks the execution of javascript code (and the change detection) until the user clicked on the button. In that case, maybe you can replace `alert("Game over!");` with `setTimeout(() => alert("Game over!"), 0);` (or implement your own non-native alert in CSS)

Answer (score 0):

From method name I can guess that it isn't bound with any event which triggers angular change detection cycle, so you may need to do it manually. Try using `ChangeDetectionRef.detectChanges()`

Comment: How can i know if something triggers angular change detection cycle or not? Shouldn't it be triggered every time i change a property i use in the component.html? Tnx a lot for your help!

Comment: check your component tree to see if any of the parent component is set to changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush. If a parent is set, then all of its children will have this set, and you will need to add the detechChanges() function to be able to trigger a change.